# Challenges performing basic HTTP authentication on RPC SOAP client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, casting, xml-rpc

Been trying to follow some online examples as I need to do basic authentication on a webservice client.

I generated the stub classes of the project using wsimport and tried passing the authentication credentials using `javax.xml.rpc.stub` class but casting the proxy class throws a java.lang.ClassCastException:

> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29 cannot be cast to javax.xml.rpc.Stub.

please can anyone review this code and point me in the right direction if am doing something wrong.

```
public class WebClientTester
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        doNameEnquiry("XXXXXXXXX");
    }

    public static void doNameEnquiry(String acct)
    {

        boolean txnOk = false;
        try
        {

            String str = "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/GwHolderService.svc?wsdl";
            URL url = new URL(str.substring(0, str.indexOf("?")));
            QName qname = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "GwHolderService");

            Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

            SInfoHolder port = (SInfoHolder) service.getPort(SInfoHolder.class);

            ((javax.xml.rpc.Stub) port)._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "myUser");
            ((javax.xml.rpc.Stub) port)._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "myPwd");

            InfoHolderRequest request = new InfoHolderRequest();
            request.setHolderAccountNumber(acct);
            InfoHolderResponse response = port.infoHolder(request);

            // System.out.println("authenticated: "+
            // response.getRespMessageCode());
            System.out.println("******************END RESPONSE***********");
            System.out.println("responseCode: " + response.getCoderesp());
            System.out.println(processResponseXML(response));
            System.out.println("******************LIST DETAILS***********");
            listDetails(processResponseXML(response));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return txnOk;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `SInfoHolder` implementing the Interface `javax.xml.rpc.Stub`?

Comment: no, SInfoHolder is a generated interface (from wsimport tool). and does not implement javax.xml.rpc.Stub

Comment: well there exactly is the problem... you can't cast an object to an interface/class which it doesn't implement/extend